# How do I configure web scenario dependencies using zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

Using Zabbix 3.2.

We have a webserver - web-01.org, running nginx.

On this will be

website1.org
website2.org
website3.org

etc

In order to use a web monitoring template in Zabbix, i've configured all of these as separate hosts, rather than web-scenarios on the web server as this didnt seem to allow multiple web addresses anywhere.

How can I set the web scenario for the different sites so that they depend on the relevant nginx check on the web server.

I can see trigger dependencies for some rules, but not for web-scenarios.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To alert on anything in Zabbix, you still need triggers. Triggers can also reference web scenario items. That way the triggers on web scenarios can depend on other triggers.

Please note that you can easily have multiple web scenarios on the same host, as you can simply specify the target website in the step "URL" field.

Comment: Adding a trigger allows me to create a dependency that points to the correct item.